# Can I still solo level 3 raids remotely?

Tags: pokemon-go

With the just released remote raid option within Pokémon Go, I would like to know if I can still solo level 3 raids. For example, I can solo Alolan Raichu quite easily now. However, raiding remotely deals less damage, which could endanger my chances, especially with the time limit. How much less damage (in percentage) do I do remotely, and what would my non-remote leftover time need to be so that I can safely do the remote raid?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time of writing, there is no damage reduction in place for remote raiding. The damage reduction will come at an undisclosed date, so there is currently no way of knowing what the reduced damage output will be.

> At launch, Trainers battling in raids remotely will have the same attack power as Trainers who are able to battle at the raid location in person. Afterward, a Trainer battling at the raid location in person will have higher attack power than a Trainer battling remotely
>
> <sub>[Source](https://pokemongolive.com/en/post/raidbattleupdate-april2020/)</sub>

So, in the mean time, you can still solo 3 star while remote raiding as if you were physically at the raid. [Data miners](https://www.reddit.com/r/TheSilphRoad/comments/g95i1l/game_master_update_04272020_remote_raids_have/) have confirmed this. The code shows the current damage multiplier being set to 1.0. I will keep tabs on this thread and update my answer with new information

If you also navigate to the today tab in Pokémon Go, there is a line item under "Special Bonuses" indicating that remote raiding has boosted damage (which, in turn offsets the damage reduction). This "Special Bonus" has been present since Niantic launched their play-at-home campaign due to Covid-19. So it's likely the damage reduction will take effect after shelter-in-place orders start being lifted and things go back to normal

[image: today tab showing boosted damage]